# Calculating flux through a cylinder bounded by $x^2+y^2=9$ and $z=0$, $z=5$. If $F(x,y,z) = (3x, y^3,-2.z^2)$, then calculate the flux of F through C.

Tags: vector-fields

This was supposed to be a pretty straight forward question. The basic turn the crank and get the answer. 
I parametrized the integral:

$\vec r=(3cos(t),3\sin(t),z)$

$d\vec r=(-3sin(t),3\cos(t),0)d\theta+(0,0,1)dz$

$\hat n=(3cos(t),3sin(t),0)$ $dtdz$

and 
$F = (9cos(t),9sin(t),-2z^2)$

$\iint_{S} F.\hat n\mathrm dS$

$\iint_{S} (9cos(t),27sin^3(t),-2z^2).(3cos(t),3sin(t),0)dzdt$

$5\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^5 [27cos^2(t)+81sin^4(t)] \mathrm dzdt$

$=(1755\pi)/4$

BUT!
This is wrong. This ain`t the right answer.

I then tried the divergence theorem to convert it to a volume integral, and still, no luck.

And then, I tried breaking it into three parts. One over the curved surface of the cylinder, then the 2 flat (top-bottom) surfaces, and still failed to get the correct answer that seems to be: $-45\pi/4$.

Any idea why my approach to the problem is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, except for a couple of typos.  You must be calculating the flux through the upper and lower surfaces incorrectly.  On the upper surface, the unit normal is $(0,0,1)$ and $F(x,y,z)=(3x,y^3,-50)$ so the flux is $-50\cdot3^2\pi={-1800\pi\over4}.$  On the lower surface, the unit normal is $(0,0,-1)$ and the flux is $0$, since $z=0$.

Adding these to your result gives ${-45\pi\over4}$.

Comment: Oh, I was nearly there. I don`t know how I became so silly and forgot about that. I kept thinking that flux through both the top and the bottom was the same, so just kept multiplying it by a factor of 2.
Thank you so much, Saulsaptz

Comment: Actually, the hint to the problem says that I should use Stokes Theorem, which makes no sense because, as far as I know, Stokes converts contour integrals to surface integrals, and the other way around is usually very hard. So that kept me in some other weird thoughts.
Maybe, it meant that I should take the curl of the curl and then calculate the volume integral? It still seems like a little too much work.

Comment: @Dante_7744 They mean the divergence theorem.  There is a more general form of Stokes' theorem, of which Green's theorem, the divergence theorem, and the form of Stokes' theorem you refer to are special cases.  It should be less work to compute the integral of $\div F$ over the volume, I would think.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know the divergence theorem, and I did try that too, and now I made it work.
I found the more general form of Stokes theorem yesterday when I started reading 'Calculus on Manifolds'. So now I get it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Dante_7744 You're welcome.  I just noticed in my last comment that `$\div F$` comes out as $\div F$.  I hope you figured out what I meant.

Comment: Yes, yes, I think you were referring to Gauss`s Divergence Theorem that we use to calculate fluxes in mostly symmetrical cases